# Regular expression help for tv series in Java

Tags: java, regex

I will say that i am very weak in my knowledge of regular expressions... I am trying to match tv series file names in **java**, like the following:

xyz title name S01E02 bla bla
bla bla title name.S03E04
the season title name s05e03

However my solution is working, it only is matching **name s01e02** or **name.s03e03** Not the complete name of the tv series

my current regular expression is :

`(\\w+)((\\.|\\s)[sS]([0-9]{2})[eE]([0-9]{2}))`

Comment: Um, I think that's a Java string, not a regular expression.  Could you please edit the question to *not* include the eexxttrraa bbaacckkssllllaasshheesses that Java makes you include? It just complicates matters.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a suggestion:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(.*?)[.\\s][sS](\\d{2})[eE](\\d{2}).*");

String[] tests = { "xyz title name S01E02 bla bla",
                   "bla bla title name.S03E04",
                   "the season title name s05e03" };

for (String s : tests) {
    Matcher m = p.matcher(s);
    if (m.matches())
        System.out.printf("Name: %-23s Season: %s Episode: %s%n",
                m.group(1), m.group(2), m.group(3));
```

Prints:

```
Name: xyz title name          Season: 01 Episode: 02
Name: bla bla title name      Season: 03 Episode: 04
Name: the season title name   Season: 05 Episode: 03
```

Comment: You really never want to use `(?:\.|\s)` when `[.\s]` will do, because the latter is much, much faster. The Java regex compiler does not appear to have a microgram of intelligence in this regard to apply the obvious optimization, but it's hard to tell, since it also lacks any ability to debug the compiled pattern and trace resulting match. Also, if you compile with `Pattern.COMMENTS` or start off with `(?x)`, it will allow you to space out your pattern so that it can be read. You can also include Perl comments, but Java's lack of multiline strings works against you there.

Comment: How does one get the end of the string?
For example the first line how do I get "bla bla".

Comment: Put the trailing `.*` inside `(`...`)`, like `(.*)` and access it through `m.group(4)`.

Answer (score 1):

This is because of the `(\\w+)` you have at the beginning which matches a single word.

To make it match a group of words separated by space replace it with:

```
(\\w+\\s+)+
```

Answer (score 1):

This pattern might work better:

```
(?xi) ^ (?: \b \w+ \s*? ) + [\s.] S \d{2} E \d{2} $
```

You'll have to add extra backslashes if this pattern is a literal Java string rather than read in from elsewhere.

Also, this only works on ASCII data, not full Unicode, because Java's regexes refuse to budge on the old regex shortcuts.  You would have to use Unicode properties then. It's rather unpleasant, but if that might be the case, please tell me and I'll update the pattern to work for Unicode.